# API php with multiple columns going to one id

Tags: javascript, php, api

In my database I have multiple columns like this

Questions

```
question one with questionID 1
question two with questionID 2
...
```

Answers

```
answer one with questionID 1
answer two with questionID 1
answer one with questionID 2
answer two with questionID 2
```

To retrieve them I usually works as the example below:

> $sql = "SELECT * FROM Questions 
>   LEFT JOIN Answers ON Questions.questionID = Answers.questionID";

getting this outcome:

```
[{
    "questionID": "1",
    "question": "Test Question",
    "potID": "1",
    "optionID": "1",
    "optionValue": "answer 1",
    "isCorrect": "0"
}, {
    "questionID": "1",
    "question": "Test Question",
    "potID": "1",
    "optionID": "2",
    "optionValue": "answer 2",
    "isCorrect": "1"
}]
```

How can I get the data as following

```
[{
    "questionID": "1",
    "question": "Test Question",
    "potID": "1"
{Answers: [
    "optionID": "1",
    "optionValue": "answer 1",
    "isCorrect": "0"
}, {
    "optionID": "2",
    "optionValue": "answer 2",
    "isCorrect": "1"
]}
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use cycle inside another cycle to collect all answer to specific question. How I usually do this using `PHP`:

```
$questions = [
    ['questionID' => 1, 'question' => 'What is my name?', 'answers' => []]
];

$answers = [
    ['answerID' => 1, 'value' => 'John', 'questionID' => 1, 'isCorrect' => 1],
    ['answerID' => 2, 'value' => 'Paul', 'questionID' => 1, 'isCorrect' => 0]
];

foreach ($questions as $question) {
    foreach ($answers as $answer) {
        if ($answer['questionID'] == $question['questionID']) {
            $question['answers'][] = $answer;
        }
    }
}

// output should be something like this
[
    'questionID' => 1, 'question' => 'What is my name?', 'answers' => [
        ['answerID' => 1, 'value' => 'John', 'questionID' => 1, 'isCorrect' => 1],
        ['answerID' => 2, 'value' => 'Paul', 'questionID' => 1, 'isCorrect' => 0]
    ]
]
```

You need to make something similar to this using your language.